# PDO - Could not find device driver Error 256 PostgreSql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when I execute my code. According to my phpinfo.php file, I have the driver associated with Postgresql (`pgsql`).  I'm working through Apress' Beginning PHP and Postgresql E-Commerce the link for the source files can be found here: http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781590596487

I'm on chapter 3, even when I try to run the source files, I get this error.  But it also doesn't work with my code (same error). I'm also using WAPP.

**This is my config.php file where the database constants live**

```
define('DB_PERSISTENCY', 'true');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME','hatshopadmin');
define('DB_PASSWORD','carmen77');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'hatshop');
define('PDO_DSN', 'psql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE);
```

**Then in the database_handler.php file the erorr is produced when the `GetHandler()` function is called and a new PDO object is created**

```
  private static function GetHandler()
      {
        // Create a database connection only if one doesn't already enchant_broker_dict_exists
        if(!isset(self::$_mHandler))
        {
          // Execute code catching potential exceptions
          try {
            // Create a new PDO class instance
            self::$_mHandler = new PDO(PDO_DSN,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => DB_PERSISTENCY));

            // Configure PDO to throw excpetions
            self::$_mHandler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            // CLose the database handler and trigger an error
            self::Close();
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(),E_USER_ERROR);
          }
        }
```

**Here's the text output of the error trigger and backtrace**

```
[![ERRNO: 256
TEXT: could not find driver
LOCATION: C:\hatshop\business\database_handler.php, line 30, at December 6, 2016, 12:22 pm
Showing backtrace:
trigger_error("could not find driver", "256") # line   30, file: C:\hatshop\business\database_handler.php
DatabaseHandler.GetHandler() # line   48, file: C:\hatshop\business\database_handler.php
DatabaseHandler.Prepare("SELECT * FROM catalog_get_departments_list();") # line   10, file: C:\hatshop\business\catalog.php
catalog.GetDepartments() # line   35, file: C:\hatshop\presentation\smarty_plugins\function.load_departments_list.php
DepartmentsList.init() # line    7, file: C:\hatshop\presentation\smarty_plugins\function.load_departments_list.php
smarty_function_load_departments_list(Array\[1\], Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) # line   27, file: C:\hatshop\presentation\templates_c\0a1d7dc51ed184ccb86b9e920ba0ed32fc03c1d8_0.file.departments_list.tpl.php
content_5845d138b445a1_60892576(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) # line  128, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_template_resource_base.php
Smarty_Template_Resource_Base.getRenderedTemplateCode(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) # line  172, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_template_compiled.php
Smarty_Template_Compiled.render(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) # line  206, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php
Smarty_Internal_Template.render() # line  372, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php
Smarty_Internal_Template._subTemplateRender("file:departments_list.tpl", null, null, "0", "3600", Array\[0\], "0", false) # line   42, file: C:\hatshop\presentation\templates_c\035bebc58026386c22a5b090fe285e8f2accbb65_0.file.index.tpl.php
content_5845d13873fa28_32066997(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) # line  128, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_template_resource_base.php
Smarty_Template_Resource_Base.getRenderedTemplateCode(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) # line  172, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_template_compiled.php
Smarty_Template_Compiled.render(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) # line  206, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php
Smarty_Internal_Template.render(false, "1") # line  216, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase._execute("index.tpl", null, null, null, "1") # line  122, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase.display("index.tpl") # line    9, file: C:\hatshop\index.php]
```

[image]